# Problem with TeXcount related to file-including commands

Tags: texcount

I have found TeXcount extremely useful and, for all my needs so far, most accurate. Nonetheless, I have observed a strange behavior with `TeXcount 3.0 (beta)` when trying to make the script aware of files being included with the macro `\InputIfFileExists`.

Everything goes fine if I append the command directly in the script `texcount.pl` as follows:

```
my %TeXfileinclude=('\input'=>'input','\include'=>'texfile','\InputIfFileExists'=>'file');
```

But in order to not have this setting overwritten when upgrading to a next (or the same, but stable) version, I am using an options file. The line

```
%fileinclude \InputIfFileExists file
```

leads to some error when I run `texcount`. The error no longer appears and the scripting proceeds perfectly as soon as I comment that line with the hash sign, `#`, corresponding to Perl.

Is there something wrong with the way that I am proceeding?

Comment: I am having a similar problem - amongst my preamble I have defined a new column type `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}` . Texcount only works when this line is commented out, it appears that the hash sign `#` is causing the problem. Perhaps its simply that the hash symbol isn't taken into account when texcount is parsing the source code?